# How to upgrade brew ssh after recent client exploit?

Tags: macos, homebrew, ssh, openssl

I'm running OS X El Capitan 10.11.1

Since the recently discovered SSH client exploit mentioned [here](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20160114142733) I wanted to take action to secure myself. In the process I noticed I'm using Apple's ssh and not the brew version I have installed. So I wanted to change that. One of the things I need to do is edit the file below to point to `/usr/local/bin/ssh-agent` instead of the system default `/usr/bin/ssh-agent`. However, even as sudo, I cannot edit this file. It only opens as readonly.

```
sudo vi /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist
```

How can I open this file in read/write mode?

Comment: Yes it was. I deleted the other question. I was hand migrating my original question and didn't realize someone else was migrating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to modify certain directories/files in OS X El Capitan you have to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) AKA “rootless”:

1. Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
2. In the menubar click Utilities > Terminal.
3. In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil disable`.
4. Restart your Mac.
5. After finishing your mods re-enable it in Recovery Mode with `csrutil enable`.

---

The file */System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist* may be replaced in the next system update.